# Regex: how to extract from keys and values from '+key:value+key2:"value+value"+'?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have an input string like: `+key:value+key2:"value+value"+` I would like a regex that returns the following form me: `key:value` and `key:"value+value"`

Ideally, I would want to wrap it inside a function that returns an object like this:

```
{
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value+value'
}
```

Basically value can be anything - any character. The only rule here is actually that when there is a + sign inside the value, this should not delimit the regex operation.

Comment: Regexes cannot return such dictionaries.

Comment: How do you distinguish between a `+` that delimits values and keys and one that is part of the value?

Comment: @FelixKling Presumably by whether or not it is between a set of double quotes.

Comment: @cdhowie: Ah right... I didn't interpret it that way first, but makes completely sense now.

Comment: @cdhowie: exactly. To Rob: The regex itself does not have to return such object, what I meant is that I'd like a function that (probably) uses regex to return such an object.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NRhST/) is a quickly constructed regexp and [here](http://jsperf.com/create-dict-with-regexp) is the benchmark, exercise for the reader (you) to understand it. (`/\+([^:]+):((?:(?!")[^+]+)|"([^"]*)")/g`)

Comment: @robW Thanks! I'm trying to educate myself with regex, but it's slow to come for me. I appreciate your input!

Comment: One non-capturing group is optional, by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/NRhST/1/, `/\+([^:]+):((?!")[^+]+|"([^"]*)")/g`. It appears to be almost ten times faster than dystroy's answer, but that's likely caused by the difference in how both solutions are implemented (dystroy's method looks relatively expensive).

Comment: @RobW my code could be made faster, I don't think speed is very relevant here so I mainly wanted to make it clear. But your code is very pretty, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function parseRagulkasString(str) {
    var regex = /\+([^:]+):((?!")[^+]*|"([^"]*)")/g, o = {}, match;
    while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null)
        o[match[1]] = match[match[3] === undefined ? 2 : 3];
    return o;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NRhST/2/

#### Explanation

- `\+` matches a literal plus.
- `([^:]+)` matches any non-`:` signs, and is captured as the first group.
- `:` matches a literal colon.
- `( ... )` captures the second group:

  - `(?!")[^+]*` If not followed by a quote, match all consecutive non-plus characters.
  - `|` otherwise
  - `"([^"]*)"` match all non-quote characters within quotes, and capture this group (3).

The while loop repetitively runs the regular expression for the input string, and handles all matches as follows:

- `match[1]` is the first captured group, and is used as the key.
- If the value is not quoted, `match[3]` is `undefined` and `match[2]` is the value.
- Otherwise, `match[3]` contains the contents within the quotes, and `match[2]` contains the contents including quotes.

For example (`+key:value+key2:"value+value"+`):

```js
match[0] = 'key:value'   match[0] = 'key2:"value+value"'
match[1] = 'key'         match[1] = 'key2'
match[2] = 'value'       match[2] = '"value+value"'
match[3] = undefined     match[3] = 'value+value'
```

Because `match[2]` only makes sense if the value is not quoted, we first check if `match[3]` is `undefined`. If yes, the value is not quoted and we use the second group. Otherwise, the third group is used.

Note: This implementation requires the format as specified in the question (the last plus sign is optional). You can validate if the input string matches the expected format using:

```js
function isRagulkasString(str) {
    return /^(\+[^:]+:((?!")[^+]*|"[^"]*"))+\+?$/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: +1 for a pretty regex solution

Comment: +1 for the step by step explanations on the regex

Comment: It should be noted (not a critic) that this version, as it is, would fail if the string isn't strictly as required, for example `'"clef":valeur++key2:"value+value"+'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex for that isn't the simplest solution.

Here's a solution :

```
var str = '+key:value+key2:"value+value"+';
var o = {};
str.split('"').map(function(v,i){
  return i%2 ? v.replace(/\+/, 'ù') : v
}).join('').split('+').forEach(function(v){
  var t = v.split(':');
  if (t.length==2) o[t[0]]=t[1].replace(/ù/,'+');
});
console.log(o);
```

It supposes you don't have `ù` in your string. If it may be the case, the code might be tuned to use another (longer) separator.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/iyimaz/1/edit) (open the console)

Note that if you want to be compatible with IE8, you'll have to use a `for` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: So the idea is to replace the + inside double quotes with an unlikely character and then split it into keys? That could work. I wonder what is the performance of this vs regex...

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @ragulka the idea is that if the character that serves as separator (+ in your case) is found within a value, it should be escaped. That's how querystrings work for example (with the & character).

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for the quick response. I like this answer and will mark it as the correct one, but I will probably use RobW's regex from the comments in the end.

Comment: Well. RobW could also write an answer and you could accept it.